# ConcurrentModificationException in facade implemention

Tags: java, facade

I'm implementing this facade to wrap the LinkedList,TreeSet and HashSet classes in java.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class CollectionFacadeSet implements SimpleSet{
protected java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> collection;
private Iterator<java.lang.String> iterator;
private int count;
/**
* Creates a new facade wrapping the specified collection.
* @param collection - The Collection to wrap.
 */
public CollectionFacadeSet(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String> collection){

    this.collection=collection;
    iterator = this.collection.iterator();
    count=0;
}
/**
* Add a specified element to the set if it's not already in it.
* @param newValue New value to add to the set
* @return False iff newValue already exists in the set
*/
public boolean add(java.lang.String newValue){
    if(contains(newValue))
        return false;
    collection.add(newValue);
    return true;
}
/**
* Look for a specified value in the set.
* @param searchVal Value to search for
* @return True iff searchVal is found in the set
*/
public boolean contains(java.lang.String searchVal){
    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        java.lang.String myString=iterator.next(); //issue
        System.out.println(myString);
        if(myString.equals(searchVal))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In the contain function, once I'm creating a string to host the next(current) object, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)`
```

I've followed pretty much the way its written in other question but it appears my loop still throws an exception.

Comment: Why are you fully-qualifying the names? `java.lang.String` isn't necessary: just use `String`. You need to `import java.util.Collection;`, but then you can just write `Collection` instead of `java.util.Collection`.

Comment: That's how our university staff wants them... They also asked us to iterate a collection without iterator until 3 days ago :\

Answer (score 2):

Your `add` method modifies the collection after you create the iterator.

Instead of having the iterator in a member variable, declare it inside the `contains` method:

```
public boolean contains(java.lang.String searchVal){
  Iterator<String> iterator = collection.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    // ...
```

The other problem with your current code is that your `contains` method exhausts the iterator - once you've gone through it once and found that the element is not contained, it does not reset, meaning the `contains` method wouldn't find the element next time. Declaring it as a local variable fixes this problem too.

---

Of course, you don't really need the `Iterator` at all, other than the fact that you're printing out the elements. (I'd guess you're just doing this for debugging; it's not really useful).

You can simply use `Collection.contains`:

```
public boolean contains(String searchVal) {
  return collection.contains(searchVal);
}
```